# PDFsharp (1.50.5147) setting OwnerPassword mixes up document colors

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp

When setting "OwnerPassword" (Encrypted128Bit) (Or setting PdfDocumentSecurityLevel.Encrypted40Bit) on a PDF created by Microsoft PowerPoint 2016, this PDF's first page image get it's colors messed up (randomized, kind of inverted). 
PDFs created with Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 has no such problem.

Any ideas where to dig in?

PS.: There is no such problem with older (1.3) version of PDFsharp, however then these mixed-color-pdfs are not getting watermarked instead. Maybe it has something to do with iref streams (whatever it means)...

Edit:

When I tried to open existing PDF with PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import, extract all the images out of it and put them into newly created PdfDocument (so that PDF Producer in such case is: PDFsharp 1.50.5147 (not PowerPoint)) and tried to set OwnerPassword to that newly (with images) created PDF - colors still got mixed up.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.
Is there already a solution

Comment: @Marcel, I don't know, not following this since asked the question because, in my case we just ditched off Password Protection of files.